# Why does initial blank activity show on startup?

Tags: android

In my android app I have an initial activity which popup a dialog (used as the splash screen). I am doing this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Popup a fullscreen dialog (used as splash)
        showSplashScreen();
 }
```

However there is a small time period before this where a blank empty with my logo and title bar show up.  I have no idea how to remove this from showing at all. I even tried to see if this was coming from the same activity, I check by removing the title bar by requesting no title bar. However, I had no luck... This mysterious blank activity shows up for a small time interval.

How do apps like facebook show an initial splash screen first without showing anything else before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. use `setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);` in the code.
2. Describe the Activity that you want to open as a dialogue in the manifest file as:

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".Description_Activity"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
   </activity>
   ```

Comment: This is the answer. You my friend are an angel sent from above. <3 Thank you. I've been stumped on this for the longest.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. But i am using customActionBar. And i can not disable title. what should i do ?

Answer (score 4):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in onCreate or

```
android:theme=”@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar”
```

in your activity tag of manifest should hide the title bar.

And please make sure this activity is your first activity on start.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following line to my custom style:

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```