# using actionbar from support library unexpected behaviour

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

It is the first time of using Action Bar from Support library, and it is working fine and show the action bar, but I have notice that there is an empty screen open on application lunch before my launcher activity, and hide in 1 second, can any one tell me how to get ride from this empty screen.

Thanks.

Comment: its not about the actionbar issue, its when creating the application window

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061895/why-does-initial-blank-activity-show-on-startup

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432594/blank-page-on-startup and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546703/how-to-fix-white-screen-on-app-start-up

Comment: but before I extend the action bar activity and use Theme.AppCompat.Light as my application style, the application was open very normally, without the activity before my splash screen.

Comment: Yes, if you noticed in the answers i commented here, the solution mostly by fixing the theme it self, so the old theme you were using didn't has this issue, but the new one do.